# Webix Component not getting refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, webix

```
function update_grouplist_items(){
    //console.log("calling1");
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $$("cfg").reconstruct()
    }, 3000);
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    xhrFields:{
        withCredentials: true
    },
    beforeSend: function(request){
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", 'application/json');
    },
    cache: false,
    url:savedataUrl,
    data : JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'),
    processData: false,
    success: update_grouplist_items,
});
```

I am trying to reload the "cfg" component(list) on success. I see that it gets refreshed (new item is added) when I keep the debugger console open. But when the console is closed I see the component getting refreshed but no item added to the list. (Basically I would see the component flicker). I am using Internet Explorer as my browser. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

All data componets provide clearAll and parse API, so to reload group list in most effective manner you need to use something like next

```
list.clearAll();
list.parse(new_data);
```

It will repaint the data only and will minimize the flickering.

https://docs.webix.com/api__link__ui.proto_clearall.html
https://docs.webix.com/api__link__ui.proto_parse.html